# Atlassian Stash and git SSL issue

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I am connecting from `GIT` client to a repo in `STASH` and it works fine if I have `SSLverify=false`, but I would like it to work with `SSL`.

I have done the following steps

1. Imported the Certificates using Firefox and saved the `PEM` file under `git/bin` folder
2. set `git config --system http.SSLCAinfo` to the `cert.pem` file

But when I try to pull it gives the error `"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`

This is what I have in my git config

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/cert.pem
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
gui.recentrepo=H:/customerSrv
gui.recentrepo=H:/New folder
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/cert.pem
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=https://***@stash.***.net/scm/at/customersrv.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/cert.pem
```

PS: I know the server uses a Self Signed Certificate so a `cacert.pem` file does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you have your terminology slightly mixed up: a stash is a specific concept in Git, and doesn't involve connecting to anything else.  Are you connecting to a server called 'stash', or using the command `git stash`?  It would help if you could show us the command you've written and the complete error.

Comment: Andrew, he's talking about Atlassian Stash (for which I am a developer)

https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/